# Прерывание загрузки данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

как можно реализовать прерывание загрузки данных в базу MySQL по требованию пользователя (кнопка отмены загрузки) в php?

можно ли это вообще реализовать без разрыва соединения? в гугле не нашел подобного.

Comment: Поставил минус поскольку вопрос представляет из себя [XY проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy). Вопрос необходимо переформулировать, изложив изначальную задачу, как можно более полно

Comment: @Ипатьев, переформулировал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделал так:

1. создал таблицу с полями `cancel` и `status`
2. вызываю метод запускающий консольное приложение через `exec` (cd basedir && php controller/init), который запускает метод загрузки json.
3. метод загрузки записывает в таблицу (в запись с `id == 1`) `cancel = 1` и `status = 1`, при переборе элементов делается проверка `cancel`, и если он `!= 1` возвращаю делаю `return`.
4. кнопка `отмена` вызывает метод `cancel`, который ставит `$model->cancel = 0` и `status = 0`.
5. `status` нужен только для проверки состояния загрузки, т.е. 0 - ожидание, 1 - идет загрузка, 2 - завершено.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю со стороны пользователя это не возможно. Со стороны сервера обратите внимание на две переменные конфигурации - max_execution_time, max_file_upload - пишу по памяти, наверняка с ошибкой. Первая ограичит время выполнения скрипта, вторая величену максимальную для аплоада- загрузки.

Пока писал, придумал как это можно сделать. Разбейте sql на несколько запросов. Запускайте их по одному, каждый раз проверяя что пользователь не отменил загрузку. Отменять пользователь будет кнопкой, которая запускаяет аякс, и при получении такого запроса, на стороне сервера устанавливается сессионая переменная.
Скрипт который запускает запросы проверяет после каждого установленна ли эта переменная, для того чтоб обнаружить ее вовремя вероятно необходимо закрыть и снова открыть сессию.

Оберните запросы в транзакцию, если не хотите чтоб данные частично загрузились, а только полностью или никак.

Comment: да, как раз хотел реализовать этот вариант (разбиение и проверка), но не знал, насколько правильно так делать. спасибо.

Comment: отсюда вытекает мой следующий вопрос.
я перебираю файл json (около 100к значений), как мне запомнить позицию, где остановился перебор, чтобы каждый раз заново не делать перебор? иначе уж больно затратно выходит.

Comment: Переделать json так что бы 100к значений были в массиве, не объекте

Comment: в смысле, переделать? при отправке? или при принятии? json формирую не я. а после принятия да, делаю json_decode и уже после работаю с ним.

Comment: Это я к тому что если массив то ваш вопрос "запомнить позицию" решаемый

Comment: а как хранить его состояние между запросами?

Comment: Через веб страницу делаете? Храните в сессии. Или если страница не перезагружается то в яваскрипт переменной

Comment: в любом случае при каждом запросе мне придется грузить json и заново преобразовывать в массив, и уже потом перебирать с нужного места. и это проблема. как оптимизировать загрузку?